# Process/Flow of PHP autoloader when using namespaces

Tags: php, optimization, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I'm in the middle of adapting to namespaces and using `spl_autoload_register()`, but still struggling with understanding some aspects. For example, I have this current example working but I don't understand why there is an extra call made. Let me explain...

**I have a "services" directory that houses service based classes:**

- *services*

  - *div-services-debug.php*
  - *div-services-helper.php*
  - *div-services-etc.php*

**In my class I register my autoload function like so:**

```
spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'services' ) );

private function services( $class ) {
    # If not a service don't bother
    if (strpos($class, 'DIV\\services') === false) return;

    $class = str_replace('\\', '-', strtolower($class));
    if( is_file($this->path['services_dir'].$class.'.php') )
        require $this->path['services_dir'].$class.'.php';
}
```

**Example service looks something like this:**

```
namespace DIV\services{

    if ( ! class_exists( 'debug' ) ) :
        class debug{

            public static function scripts() {
                ...
            }

        }
     endif;

}
```

**I then implement a service like so:**

```
DIV\services\debug::scripts();
```

---

Easy enough, but when running through some debugging on the autoloader method I'm noticing that with that call to the service I get 2 passes ($class = current class being passed through autoloader):

1. $class = DIV\services\helper

This I expected considering the call. But then I see another iteration

2. $class = helper

**Why is this one call executing 2 attempts to autoload?**

Both `DIV\services\helper` and `helper` are being called from the one implementation call. Is this how namespaces function? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Xtremefaith, currently I am using this way

```
function __autoload($class){
    spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
    $normalized = __DIR__ . 
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . 
            spl_autoload_extensions();//normalize

    if (!file_exists($normalized)) {
        throw new Exception('Autoload Exception: File can not be loaded.');
    } else {
        require_once $normalized; //include file
    }
}
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

And to call:

```
new \DIV\ClassName();
```

I hope this can help you in some way.